# When is mandatory define each value for SqlConfig.TransactionMode for @SqlConfig?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-test

About Spring Framework Test, for the [@SqlConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlConfig.html) annotation, it has some valuable attributes such as:

- `dataSource`: where is possible define an explicit *dataSource*. It in case the app has **2** `DataSources` defined and one of them has `@Primary` but is need it the second in the Test class.
- `transactionManager`: the same as above, therefore must be selected the *transactionManager* according the secondary *dataSource* - it to keep the same pair working together. *Correct me if I am wrong*.

Therefore the `@Service` and `@Repository` are tested based on their `@Transactional` settings

The reason of this post is about the `transactionMode` attribute that works through the [SqlConfig.TransactionMode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/SqlConfig.TransactionMode.html) enum with three values:

```
DEFAULT
INFERRED
ISOLATED
```

I read the javadoc, but is not clear when use *explicitly* any of them, specially the latest.

**Consideration**

The app, for production, is going to work really with the current infrastructure based according with the *primary* and *secondary* pairs of `DataSource`s and `TransactionManager`s and the `@Transactional` settings. *Therefore that infrastructure must be tested*.

**Question**

- When is mandatory define each value for `SqlConfig.TransactionMode` for `@SqlConfig`?

Why use an alternative configuration against the expected and real configuration mentioned in the *Consideration* section?